# How to create a P2SH address with bitcore-lib

Tags: bitcore

I was looking to create custom P2SH addresses from `redeemScripts` ( they start with 3...) using `bictore-lib`.

If anyone can direct me to the right code in their module, I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reference for creating a P2SH multisig address https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/addresses.js#L44

However your question states "custom" P2SH so I think you might be asking about something more advanced, in which case I would suggest reviewing `bitcoin.script.compile`, the CLTV address for example:

```js
    let bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib");
    let bip65 = require('bip65');
    
    function cltvCheckSigOutput (aQ, bQ, lockTime) {
        return bitcoin.script.compile([
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_IF,
          bitcoin.script.number.encode(lockTime),
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY,
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_DROP,
    
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_ELSE,
          bQ.publicKey,
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY,
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_ENDIF,
    
          aQ.publicKey,
          bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSIG
        ])
      }     
    
      function utcNow () {
        return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
      }

    let NETWORK = bitcoin.networks.testnet;  
    let alice = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('cScfkGjbzzoeewVWmU2hYPUHeVGJRDdFt7WhmrVVGkxpmPP8BHWe', NETWORK); 
    let bob = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('cMkopUXKWsEzAjfa1zApksGRwjVpJRB3831qM9W4gKZsLwjHXA9x', NETWORK)
    
    //set lock time for 3 hours from now
    let lockTime = bip65.encode({ utc: utcNow() + (3600 * 3) });

    let redeemScript = cltvCheckSigOutput(alice, bob, lockTime);
    let scriptPubKey = bitcoin.script.scriptHash.output.encode(bitcoin.crypto.hash160(redeemScript));
    let address = bitcoin.address.fromOutputScript(scriptPubKey, NETWORK);

    console.log(address);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking for a JS script in `bitcoinjs-lib` or `bitcore-lib` to create NON MULTISIG, so a normal P2SH address from a `redeemScript`. Or even from a `customString` for that matter.

Comment: To be clear, in this article it mentions about a "special bitcoin address which are essentially Base58Check encodings of the 20 byte hash of the redeem script.". How are these "special addresses" created? But not the multisig ones, just an address which is the hash of a redeemScript.  https://medium.com/@ismailakkila/my-notes-on-bitcoin-transactions-part-2-c9d39d5ae326. @m1xolyd1an

Comment: Maybe this is what what I am looking for. https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/addresses.js#L25

Comment: Essentially it is just `bitcoin.script.scriptHash.output.encode(bitcoin.crypto.hash160(redeemScript));` where `redeemScript` is equal to an OP code script array `bitcoin.script.compile([bitcoin.opcodes.OP_IF,  bitcoin.script.number.encode(lockTime),...])`